# How to make simple Async wrappers with parameters

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, async-await

I want to bring an existing Forms project to VS2012 RC and add some quick Async/Await wrappers to some of the long procedures. I want to wrap existing procedures in `Async` equivalents without changing the originals.

So far I have had success like this :

```
'old synchronous function:
Public Function UpdateEverything() As Boolean
    'Do lots of predictable updates
    ...
    Return True
End Function

'new asynchronous wrapper:
Public Async Function UpdateEverythingAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
    Return Await Task.Run(AddressOf Me.UpdateEverything)
End Function
```

but that only works because `UpdateEverything` has no parameters. I can't work out the syntax if the original function has any parameters. For example, if I have:

```
'old synchronous function:
Public Function UpdateSomething(somethingID As Integer) As Boolean
    'Do updates
    ...
    Return True
End Function
```

I thought it would be:

```
Public Async Function UpdateSomethingAsync(somethingID As Integer) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Return Await Task.Run(Of Boolean)(New Func(Of Integer, Boolean)(AddressOf Me.UpdateSomething))
End Function
```

but apparently it's not that simple. Is there a simple way to wrap this in an Async equivalent without refactoring the original?

Comment: What do you mean, it's not that simple? What exactly happens with that code? Do you get a compile-time error? What does it say?

Comment: Also, see [Stephen Toub's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx), where he recommends against doing this.

Comment: sorry, it is a compile-time error. Task.Run will take a Func(Of Task), not any arbitrary Func()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Public Async Function UpdateSomethingAsync(somethingID As Integer) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Return Await Task.Run(Of Boolean)(New Func(Of Integer, Boolean)(AddressOf Me.UpdateSomething))
End Function
```

There is something weird about this method: you expect the `UpdateSomething()` method to receive the `somethingID` argument, but you never pass it to it. You can't use `UpdateSomething` directly as a delegate here, but you can use lambda:

```
Public Async Function UpdateSomethingAsync(somethingID As Integer) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Return Await Task.Run(Of Boolean)(Function() (UpdateSomething(somethingID)))
End Function
```

Although you don't need `Async` here, you can make the the method more efficient by directly returning the `Task`:

```
Public Function UpdateSomethingAsync(somethingID As Integer) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Return Task.Run(Of Boolean)(Function() (UpdateSomething(somethingID)))
End Function
```

That being said, I agree with [the Stephen Toub article I linked before](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx): don't do this, it will only confuse your users and they will be able to do it themselves if they need it.

Comment: Thanks, I agree it's a bad habit. I'm not trying it on any production code I just want a quick way to sample the features before doing too much re-factoring. I missed the anonymous function syntax, it would actually work for both of my examples.